# Block Internet Connection on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, firewall

Is this possible to block all network connections on Eclipse?

My situation is that I have unit tests in Eclipse and I want to see which of the unit tests try to connect to the network. It was hard to figure out from the source code and I think the easiest way to block the connection and see which one will be failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime I do this way:

In Eclipse preference, Genenral->Network Connections, Choose "Active Provider" to "Manual", and set invalid proxies.

Comment: I could navigate to General->Network Connections and chose "Active Provider" to "Manual" but wasn't able to set invalid proxies. I didn't see that on the menu.

Comment: In proxy entries, I see HTTP, HTTPS, SOCKS and In Proxy bypass, I could see localhost and 127.0.0.1

Comment: Just use arbitrary IP addresses for them.

Answer (score 1):

Unplug your network cable (or choose the corresponding switch in your operating system). Really, that is faster (and more reliable) than switching the proxies in eclipse manually.

If you repeatedly want to check things like this, then I find running eclipse in a virtual machine very convenient, where you can easily plug/unplug the network connector of the virtual machine by means of a single click, without disturbing your other programs.

Comment: What about of unplug the power cable? More reliable!